# why apexcharts bar graph will not display until browser resize?

Tags: javascript, laravel, bar-chart, apexcharts, domcontentloaded

I have used bar graph in apexcharts, total view count is shown in the bar graph, data is rendered from database using mysql, laravel. There is no error, but graph is not loaded in the dashboard when the page is loading but after graph is viewed after resize window. how to fix this issue?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-status-top bg-primary"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Graph View Analytics</h3>
                            <div id="chart-tasks-overview"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript**

````
      // @formatter:off
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

        var url = "{{route('user.chart')}}";
        var Count = new Array();
        var Labels = new Array();
        var Prices = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $.get(url, function(response){
            response.forEach(function(data){
                Count.push(data.count);
                let str = data.title;
                let trimmed_str = str.trim();
                let title_arr = trimmed_str.split(" ");
                //Labels.push(data.stockName);
                Prices.push(title_arr[0]+'_'+data.card_id);
            });
          });
        });

        window.ApexCharts && (new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('chart-tasks-overview'), {
            chart: {
                type: "bar",
                fontFamily: 'inherit',
                height: 320,
                parentHeightOffset: 0,
                toolbar: {
                    show: false,
                },
                animations: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    columnWidth: '50%',
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            fill: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            series: [{
                name: "View Count",
                data: Count
            }],
            grid: {
                padding: {
                    top: -20,
                    right: 0,
                    left: -4,
                    bottom: -4
                },
                strokeDashArray: 4,
            },
            xaxis: {
                labels: {
                    padding: 0,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false,
                },
                categories: Prices,
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    padding: 4
                },
            },
            colors: ["#206bc4"],
            legend: {
                show: false,
            },
        })).render();
                alert("hello12");
      });
    ```
````

Comment: is there any solution?